# Facebook API OAuth Error with instagram_basic

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api

I created a facebook app to use the IG Hashtag Search API. To connect a user I use the "Facebook Login". When creating a login url I have to specify the scope – the list of permissions – I request from the user. For my use case I need "instagram_basic", "pages_show_list" and "pages_read_engagement".

At first it worked perfectly but suddenly my requests respond with a "no permission" error and that I need the instagram_basic permission to query a hashtag. I disconnected the user and tried to reconnect but all I get is a generic facebook error on the redirected page of "Something went wrong". When removing "instagram_basic" from the scope it works – I can connect a user. But my app breaks because I need the Instagram Page ID to query a hashtag and I may not query for the Instagram Page ID without the "instagram_basic" permission.

Does anyone know what to do? The "instagram_basic" permission is listed in my apps permission with standard access. I thought maybe I need to let my app be reviewed but for the review I have to upload a video showing how the app works. But it doesn't work, because I cannot – for whatever reason – login a user with the instagram_basic permission. And I don't know why, because all facebook is giving me is a "Something went wrong" message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey, you got any solution for this?

Comment: @anurag619 Unfortunately not. After some time it just worked. Facebook is not really reliable with their APIs.